# How to correctly instantiate RestTemplate without leaking resources

Tags: spring, spring-rest, fortify

Please I have the following bean definitions

```
 @Bean
    public RestTemplate produceRestTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(restTemplateErrorHandler);
        return restTemplate;
    }

@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConn);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxPerChannel);

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(100000).build();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
}
```

The code works well but the problem is that fortify flags the code above as being potentially problematic with the following

> "The function createRequestFactory() sometimes
>   fails to release a socket allocated by createDefault() on line 141."

Please anyone with any ideas as to how to correctly do this without fortify raising alarms

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure that you don't need to do anything. It looks to be a fortify issue that it might not be updated to this usage scenario. There is a mechanism to take exceptions when working with code analyzers - these tools are not always correct.

**A Bit of Discussion**

Imagine , you are using `CloseableHttpClient` in a scenario where there would be no `@Bean` or `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` , then I would say that fortify is correct because that is the very intention of using a `java.io.Closeable` .

Spring beans are usually singleton with an intention of instance reuse so fortify should know that you are not creating multiple instances and `close()` method on AutoCloseable would be called when factory is destroyed at shutdown.

if you look at code of - `org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` , this is there.

```
/**
     * Shutdown hook that closes the underlying
     * {@link org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager ClientConnectionManager}'s
     * connection pool, if any.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        if (this.httpClient instanceof Closeable) {
            ((Closeable) this.httpClient).close();
        }
    }
```

Your fortify is looking at code in isolation and not in integrated way so its flagging.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 2 points, for solving the problem.

1. If you never call the `httpClient.close()` method, sometime you can effectivlely
   run out of socket.
2. If you're code call this method automatically somewhere there is no vuln and problem.

   Anyway, this could be a FalsePositiv depending of the Version of the Java and Lib you use